# Черный экран при запуске эмулятора android на mac os

Tags: macos, android-emulator

Я хочу запустить эмулятор android под x86_64 однако при запуске висит черный экран. Логи которые мне дает lldb:

```
2023-12-07 02:31:54.470848+0300 emulator[1427:17586] SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=20, pid=1427
2023-12-07 02:31:54.470892+0300 emulator[1427:17586] SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: emulator[1427]/0#-1 LF=0
Process 1427 stopped
* thread #2, stop reason = exec
    frame #0: 0x0000000104084040 dyld`_dyld_start dyld`:
->  0x104084040 <+0>:  movq   %rsp, %rdi
0x104084043 <+3>:  andq   $-0x10, %rsp
0x104084047 <+7>:  movq   $0x0, %rbp
0x10408404e <+14>: pushq  $0x0
Target 0: (qemu-system-x86_64) stopped.
```

Однако если я се таки исправляю ошибку и пересоздаю подписи с помощью codesign то он начинает ругаться на то что не может импортировать библиотеки .dyld